# Using Comparison<T>() comparison with the three arguments overload

Tags: c#, icomparer

I have a `List<Points>()` and I want to sort it with a custom comparer function.

I made:

```cs
public int MyCompare(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    ...
}

// In my main
// ...
points_.Sort(MyCompare); 
// ...
```

I works, all right.

Now I want to sort everything but the first element, so I thought to do:

```
points_.Sort(1, points_.Count()-1, MyCompare);
```

But with this overload he wants as argument an IComparer.

How can I solve this?

Note that `Point` **is not** a custom class, it is from Xna framework. I don't want to implement a custom class with `: IComparer`

Comment: "I don't want to implement a custom class with `: IComparer`".  Why not?

Comment: @Gjeltema There isn't a good reason, I'm just curious about how can I solve this without implement a custom class.

Comment: @misiMe Write your own `Sort` function in that case based on some property of the `Point` class

Comment: The class that implements `IComparer` is typically a different class than the class being compared. It is like `String` and `StringComparer` in the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @dasblinkenlight with .NET 4.5+ there's an ad-hoc method to convert a `Comparison<T>` delegate to an `IComparer<T>`.

But if you're stuck with a lower version, you can use this class to convert a `Comparison<T>` delegate to `IComparer<T>`:

```
    public class DelegateComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Comparison<T> compDelegate;

        public DelegateComparer(Comparison<T> compDelegate)
        {
            if (compDelegate == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("compDelegate");
            this.compDelegate = compDelegate;
        }
        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return compDelegate(x, y);
        }
    }
```

Usage example:

```
points_.Sort(1, points_.Count()-1, new DelegateComparer<Point>(MyCompare));
```

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to implement `IComparer`, you could create one from a delegate using the [`Comparer<T>.Create` static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
points_.Sort(1, points_.Count()-1, Comparer.Create(MyCompare));
```

or even

```
points_.Sort(1, points_.Count()-1, Comparer.Create((a, b) => {
    ... // comparison logic goes here
}));
```

Comment: * Supported in .NET 4.5 and up.